# In .NET MVC 3, how can I have my SearchViewModel's ID property use my custom route?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have defined the following custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "EditSearch",
               "EditUser/Edit/{userId}",
               new { controller = "EditUser", action = "Edit" }
           );
```

When I type a URL manually, the route works perfectly fine. However, when my Search page's GET form is posted, the URL appears as `../EditUser/Edit/?userId=aaa9999`. The GET form is defined in my Search.cshtml file as `@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "EditUser", FormMethod.Get ))`, and should send the `userId` parameter to the Edit action.

My Search.cshtml page has an `Html.EditorFor(model => model.userId)` which holds the userId parameter I want to be displayed in my URL address.

I would like my Search page to direct to the URL below when the "Search" button is pressed:

```
../EditUser/Edit/aaa9999
```

P.S. I know the EditUser controller name and the Edit action name are redundant, but I will be fixing that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the route values to the `BeginForm` method.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit", "EditUser", new { userId = Model.userId }, FormMethod.Get))
{
   ...
}
```

Usually when you are editing a model your url will typically look like this,

```
http://mysite.com/users/edit/1
```

And when you submit the form either GET or POST (I recommend to use POST) the form the uses the current URL and in that case all you have to use,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ...
}
```

the generated form will look like

```
<form action="/" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add userId parameter rest is fine and it will work.

> ```
> routes.MapRoute(
>                "EditSearch",
>                "EditUser/Edit/{userId}",
>                new { controller = "EditUser", action = "Edit", userId="" }
>            );
> ```